How to seal gap at bottom of garage door
There is a gap at the bottom of the garage door where it meets the foundation and the wall. It's big enough for bugs and some debris to get in the garage. How can I seal this gap? The weatherstripping on the wall and the door has been recently replaced and covers everything but the very corners.


stucco will work

What does the seal look like on the outside of the door?  There should be a vertical weatherproof seal as part of the exterior trim that goes to the bottom of the door opening.
The bottom seal of the door can be left a bit long to help close the gap.  However an overhead garage door is not 100% water or bug proof and any attempt to make it so will be met with failure.
